# how to delete the diagonal elements of a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

I need a code to omit the diagonal elements of a matrix
for example if

```
A =

[1 2 3;
 1 2 3;
 1 2 3];
```

the the output come:

```
[2 3;
 1 3;
 1 2];
```

how can i do it simply ( i know a long one but i need it simple)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
Alower = tril(A, -1);
Aupper = triu(A,  1);
result = Alower(:, 1:end-1) + Aupper(:, 2:end)
```

**Demo:**

```
> A = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3]
A =

   1   2   3
   1   2   3
   1   2   3

> tril(A, -1)(1:end, 1:end-1) + triu(A, 1)(1:end, 2:end)
ans =

   2   3
   1   3
   1   2
```

Comment: it didn't work , it gave me this error :

??? Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.

Comment: wow , i made some changes on it and it worked ...... thanks for your help,,, it was very clever

Comment: @aioobe: +1 I've used a similar trick [before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11623227/97160) :) Note that instead of `1:end` you can just write `:`. Also the syntax in the demo only works in Octave (direct indexing into result is not supported in MATLAB)

Comment: @Amro, Nice :-) Ah, right, keep forgetting these syntactical short-cuts... I'm only doing SO-Matlab atm. :)

Answer (score 3):

Notice that there are two possibilities after you eliminate the diagonal of a `n` by `n` matirx:

1. If the aftermath matrix is `n` by `n-1` (like in your question), you can do it by:

   ```
   A=A';
   A(1:n+1:n*n)=[];
   A=reshape(A,n-1,n)';
   ```
2. If the aftermath matrix is `n-1` by `n`, you can do it like this:

   ```
   A(1:n+1:n*n)=[];
   A=reshape(A,n-1,n);
   ```

Comment: This is nearly excellent but it does return a row vector rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way

```
reshape(A(setdiff(1:9,1:4:9)),[3,2])
```